# Sending an iPhone app to another developer

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, udid

I am developing an iPhone app and before submitting it to app store the client asked me to send him the app to test it first.

I have his udid number and i already added his device to the development devices list.

Now the issue is that he is far from me and there is no way for him to come and send the app for him the normal way, I mean by connecting his device to the iMac and send it from xcode.

Is there any way to send him the app to test it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, There is a way for sure. Have you heard about [**TestFlight**](https://testflightapp.com/) ?

It's a beautiful tool to send your beta apps over the air with ease. It's simple, painless, and magical. It provides app management, distribution, tracking, and centralized feedback as well as crash reporting.

You can integrate it in your App easily by following the steps given here : [**How to use TestFlight to distribute your beta app ?**](http://changhoward.blogspot.in/2012/02/ios-developer-how-to-use-testflight-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

1.Create the ipa file(build file) and sened to him.That device is already added in developer account as you told.so the app will run on that device.
2 Using Test flight.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare the ipa file and sign in to the [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) . And then click on dashboard . Then upload your ipa file . After uploading it displays the list of UDIDs which you have added to your provisioning profile . Then tick the udids which you would like to give permissiosion . And then click on the Update & Notifiy button .